# Or alternation of Regex returns more results than it should?

Tags: javascript, regex

The code is modified from https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_regexp_xy.

```html
<p>Click the button to do a global search for any of the specified alternatives (red|green).</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var str = "re, green, red, green, gren, gr, blue, yellow";
    var patt1 = /(blue|red)/;
    var result = str.match(patt1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
  }
</script>
```

The result is `red,red`. However, there is only one `red`. Why it returns two?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Return_value

Comment: `/blue|red/g` i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use groups in regexp, the `match` retunrns matched string and group (so array with two elements which are the same). Use `/blue|red/g` instead (`g` makes that `match` will continue searching after findig first match)

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = "re, green, red, green, gren, gr, blue, yellow";
  var patt1 = /blue|red/g;
  var result = str.match(patt1);
  demo.innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to do a global search for any of the specified alternatives (red|green).</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me why I need to add "global match". Without "/g", it will stop after the first match. So it should return 'red'

Comment: @user18481 it depends what do you need - If you want to get only first match then remove `g`, if you want to get all not remove it

Answer (score 2):

You should not use *Capturing Group* which works on alternatives. Remove `()` from the Regex.

Change

```
var patt1 = /(blue|red)/;
```

To

```
var patt1 = /blue|red/;
```

```html
<p>Click the button to do a global search for any of the specified alternatives (red|green).</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var str = "re, green, red, green, gren, gr, blue, yellow";
    var patt1 = /blue|red/;
    var result = str.match(patt1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me why "()" need to be removed? The format I had learned is "JavaScript RegExp (x|y) Expression"? Thanks so much!

Comment: @user18481, Capturing Group which works on alternatives which you do not in this case...